# Hibernate EventListeners Don't Intercept HQL executeUpdate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have found that neither Hibernate's `EventListener`s nor `Interceptor`s intercept **HQL executeUpdate**.

A similar thread was created on the Hibernate forum in 2011, but there is no solution given:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1012054

Many years have passed since then. What is the solution, if I want to intercept DB updates/inserts coming from HQL execution?

```
Query logicalDeleteQuery = session.createQuery(
        "update Request set activeFlag = 'N', " +
        " lastChangedById = :lastChangedById, lastChangedDate = :lastChangedDate " + 
        " where  " +
        " id = :id  ");
//...Set parameters...
logicalDeleteQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You cannot as you here by pass the entity model. You are directly doing modifications through a query. No entity listener or interceptor can help with that.

Comment: But correct me if I'm wrong, the Query still passes through Hibernate's channels? I'm not doing a direct SQL. Hibernate must process my HQL somehow.

Comment: Hibernate directly translates the HQL to SQL. Instead of detecting updates on entities and deduce SQL from that. The listener and interceptor are part of the lifecycle of entities in a JPA `EntityManager`. When using HQL or SQL you are totally skipping that.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to implement my own `Query` and override `executeUpdate` to allow interception? If so, is there a way to tell Hibernate (maybe thru configuration): whenever I do `session.createQuery()` -> give me my custom `MyQuery` implementation with that `executeUpdate` override? Basically I'm thinking of ways to hack that interception **without** using the lifecycle of entities. Is it absolutely impossible?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Could you please describe the *actual issue you're trying to solve* instead?

Comment: The issue is that I need to intercept all Insert/Update/Delete operations in my Hibernate app, in order to block them if you're a certain type of user. The app uses both Session- and Query-based operations. I'm able to intercept the Session-based code, but not this HQL executeUpdate(), and I'm looking for a global solution. See the full question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342179/how-to-comprehensively-intercept-insert-update-delete-db-transactions-in-a-hiber

Comment: No there isn't, you are bypassing the entity lifecycle. So no not with the mechanisms intended for interception of entity based changes.