# How to comprehensively intercept Insert/Update/Delete DB Transactions in a Hibernate 4 application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I created several similar threads about particular issues, but let me summarize the problem I'm facing more globally:

***GOAL***

Need to **intercept all Insert/Update/Delete DB Transactions** in an application written in Spring 4.1.5, Hibernate 4.3.8. The app uses all styles of Hibernate usage:

- Object-based through Session, e.g. `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);`
- HQL executeUpdate, e.g. `Query q = "update Obj ..."; q.executeUpdate();`
- Criteria API, e.g. `Criteria q = sessionFactory.getCurentSession().createCriteria(..); q.list();`

***Possible Approaches***

- **Interceptor**: Implement an Interceptor.

`public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {..}`

Override either (1) Transaction-level methods or (2) specific action methods.

*Transaction-level:*

```
@Override
    public void afterTransactionBegin(Transaction tx) {                 
        super.afterTransactionBegin(tx);            
    }
```

*Specific action level*:

```
@Override
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
}

@Override
public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    super.onDelete(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
}
```

- **EventListener**: Implement a `PreUpdateEventListener`, `PreInsertEventListener` and register it.

  ```
  @Component
  public class HibernateSaveUpdateEventListener implements PreUpdateEventListener, PreInsertEventListener  {
      @Override
      public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent arg0) {
          //...
      }
      @Override
      public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent arg0) {
        //...
      }
  }
  ```

***Problems***

- Neither the `EventListener` nor `Interceptor` approach intercepts **HQL executeUpdate()**. But we have many instances of that in the app. Some other users have confirmed that:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1012054

https://coderanch.com/t/669945/java/Hibernate-interceptor-working-hibernate-query

Seems like the issue is that `EventListener/Interceptor` only work with a `Session`. But **HQL executeUpdate** is on the `Query` object, not the `Session`.

- Can't use the Transaction-level Interceptor approach of `afterTransactionBegin(Transaction tx)` either. The reason is, I can't distinguish Read-Only Select Transactions from Write Transactions. `tx` doesn't tell me whether I'm in a `readOnly=false` or `readOnly=true` transaction. So the `afterTransactionBegin` override will fire for **all** transactions, and I need to limit it non-Read-Only ones only (Insert, Update, Delete).

`@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Transactional(readOnly = true)`

**So is there a solution to comprehensively intercept Insert/Update/Delete for a Hibernate app that uses both object operations and HQL operations?**

Comment: Using [StatementInspector](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-statementinspector/) and [sql parser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) might be another possible approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easy way to check for Read-Only/non-Read-Only Transactions with a **Spring-level** transaction listener, and **this will include outside SQL/HQL (non-entity)**. On the Spring level, rather than Hibernate, there's a method called `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()` that tells us if we're inside a read-only transaction we're intercepting. It can be called from the following implementation of `TransactionSynchronization` which uses a pointcut to intercept all `@Before` `@Transactional` Spring processing.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TransactionSynchronizationAspect implements TransactionSynchronization {   
    
    @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void registerTransactionSynchronization() {
        boolean isReadOnly = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();
        
        if (!isReadOnly) {
            // ... logic goes here...
        }

        // Continue
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        // No custom code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to intercept `executeUpdate()` by overriding `ASTQueryTranslatorFactory` with my own implementation:

You just need to set the hibernate property `hibernate.query.factory_class` with a custom class.

```xml
<bean lazy-init="false" id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="dataSource">
    ...
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">package.to.your.OwnASTQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
            ...other properties
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```java
public class OwnASTQueryTranslatorFactory extends ASTQueryTranslatorFactory {
    private static final Pattern INVALID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("some regexp to prevent certain queries to be executed", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    public static boolean isInvalidHql(String hql) {
        return INVALID_PATTERN.matcher(hql).find();
    }
    
    @Override
    public QueryTranslator createQueryTranslator(
            String queryIdentifier,
            String hql,
            Map filters,
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory,
            EntityGraphQueryHint entityGraphQueryHint) {
        if (isInvalidHql(hql)) {
            /**
             * My use-case was to prevent certain syntax for HQL to be executed
             * here you can add w/e you want to do when the `createQuery` is executed.
             *
             * There's a lot more you can do if you also add a custom implementation
             * of `QueryTranslatorImpl`
             * 
             **/
            throw new QueryException("Invalid HQL!", hql);
        }
        return super.createQueryTranslator(queryIdentifier, hql, filters, factory, entityGraphQueryHint);
    }
}
```